# How to call RAND method with parameter when using JPA specification

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, specifications

I am trying to make specification that will order result by random with given seed.

```
Specification<Pathway> spec = (root, query, builder) -> {
        Expression<Integer> ex = builder.literal(1);
        query.orderBy(builder.asc(builder.function("RAND", Double.class, ex)));
        return builder.and();
    };
```

I am getin an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: function takes no arguments: rand [ bla bla bla and ( 1=1 ) ) order by function('RAND', 1) asc]
```

I need to make a change so runtime executes **RAND(1)** instead of **function('RAND', 1)**. When I try to remove expression from function call like: `builder.function("RAND", Double.class)` code works, but I need to use the parameter for my implementation.

Any idea how to do it? Thank you.